# Time based php script

Tags: php, time

Say I want a php script the run the function itstime() every hour. Other than setting up a cron job on the server how can I do this?

Or is this not possible because php scripts need to be opened to be ran?

Thanks.

EDIT: I want to write some information to a log file and depending on some variables send it in an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I definitely recommend the cron job for the purpose.  But theoretically, you could have a PHP script run `itstime()`, sleep for an hour, and loop.  This is pretty crazy, though.

The script would look like:

```
<?php
include('whatever.php');
while(true) {
    itstime();
    sleep(3600);
}
?>
```

One would probably run it with `nohup php mycrazyscript.php &` to detach it from your terminal and make it keep running, and using `pkill -f mycrazyscript` to terminate it.

The reason this is crazy is that now you've got a sleeping PHP process hanging around doing nothing for 59 minutes out of every hour, and you have to make sure it's both running and running at the right time, both of which cron would take care of for you.

Comment: How would I do that? and why do you say it is crazy?

Comment: Yeah would definitely not be my choice of ways to approach it but if cron is not an option, might be the only alternative.

Comment: If I used this method would that mean then when I visited this page (To start the script) it will never finish loading?
If that is the case will the script stop running once the page is exited?

Comment: If you were going to do this, you should run the PHP script from the shell command line, not from the web.

Comment: What if shell is not an option?

Comment: Then get a new web host.  No cron and no shell?  Come on, this is 2009.

Comment: Okay, yeah, sometimes that's not an option.  Try googling for **web based cron**; there are services out there that exist to help with / take advantage of situations like this, by selling you a service where they call a Web script at some regular interval.

Answer (score 1):

Only appending to chaos' answer, so give him credit.

mrlanrat - see [this](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: adding it as a comment to @chaos answer will help to give him credit

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to cron, but do have access to a moderately busy webserver, you can use it to trigger your function every hour.  This is how WordPress gets around needing cron.  Here's how you might do it:

```
<?php
$lastrun = get_last_run_time(); // get value from database or filesystem
if( time()-$lastrun > 60*60 ) {
  itstime();
  set_last_run_time(time()); // write value back to database or filesystem
}
// The rest of your page
?>
```

Of course, there's a pretty serious race condition in this code as is.  Solving that is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: This is a good solution however This page/site will not be visited regularly so I do not think it will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.setcronjob.com/ and [various other sites](https://www.google.ie/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web%20based%20cron), provide a web based solution for this.  You can set it up to call a php script with your code in it every hour or whatever you want

```
<?php
  itstime();

?>
```